# Why some functions return the result both in return value and by writing to pointer passed?

Tags: c, posix, getcwd

Recently was reading man page of *getcwd(3)*. It writes current working directory to passed buf pointer and also returns it as pointer to char.
Could you please explain why it does so(giving result using two ways)?

Comment: Just convenience.

Comment: The pointer address may change if the given pointer is NULL

Comment: You don't have to look hard for such functions; `strcpy()`, `strcat()` and their relatives do the same.

Comment: Could you please write an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many functions write to a specified argument buffer rather than allocating their own. (This allows the caller to decide how to allocate and manage the buffer.)

However, it is often convenient for a caller to use the result directly, such as when chaining function calls, so these functions sometimes additionally return a pointer to the same buffer that was passed in.  For example:

```
char buf[256] = "foo";
puts(strncat(buf, "bar", sizeof buf - strlen(buf) - 1));
```

Comment: Why do you use `strncat()`? passing `sizeof buf - 1` is incorrect, it should be  `sizeof buf - 1 - strlen(buf)`. `strncat()` semantics are error prone and of course `strncpy()` semantics even worse so.

Comment: @chqrlie Oops, fixed. (I used `strncat` because I consider `strcat`/`strcpy`/`stncpy` to be worse.)

Answer (score 1):

One use of this is in function chaining. e.g. consider a function like `strcat`

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

This can be invoked as

```
strcat(dest, source);
```

However, if you want to concatenate 3 strings into 1, you can use function chaining

```
dest = strcat(strcat(dest, src1), src2);
```

Comment: Why store the return value into `dest`? at best redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the exact answer to this complicated question, but back at the academy my lecturer told us that it exist in order to avoid unexpected program behavior , or unexpected runtime errors.

What exactly do I mean?

For example, let's say you have to copy one string to another using 'strcpy'.
Without going into the deeper details of this function's implementation, as a general case, you should protect your data against null pointers.
Say some error has occurred during the function call, and since C doesn't quite use exceptions, it just returns Null instead.
What will happen if you just ignore the returned null value?
In this case, it will probably result in a runtime error or some unexpected behavior.

Take a look at this code:

```
char *str1 = ”Hello World”;
char *str2 = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
strcpy(str2, str1); // Error occurs, just part of the string is copied
if(!strcmp(str1,str2))
    printf(”Success”); // Never gets printed - In a more complex example you could't even figure out why
```

You should always store the result of such functions in a temporary pointer, so that your'e sure no internal error has occured.

Comment: Ok, but why some functions also write to passed pointer?
In your case you only cover returned value.

Comment: @Bulat M. For exactly the same reason - To guard your data. Those functions manage the passed buffers internally, for implementation specific purposes, yet give you indication of their success through the returned value. I think this value could also be an int or a bool, but otherwise you wouldn't be able to chain function calls.

Comment: So returned value contains status of the function operation and passed pointer points to the result of function execution?

Comment: @Bulat M. Both contain the same value upon successful execution, yet the return value is the only one that can indicate failure upon unsuccessful execution.

Answer (score 0):

when there is a need to return multiple results from a particular function we use pointers. when only one value is to be returned there is no need for pointers. 
suppose you write a function to get the time of the day. time has hours,minutes and seconds. your function needs to return 3 values, hence you pass the address of some location(or a structure) and the function will fill the address and return it to you.

same works with srtcat and strcmp etc...

Comment: It seems strange that this was the accepted answer when the original question seemed to be about why some functions return *the same thing* multiple ways, something this answer doesn't address at all.

Comment: same for `strcat` but not for `strcmp`.